# C#でJSONのシリアライズ・デシリアライズをする方法

Tags: c#, json

Pythonでは、JSONのシリアライズ・デシリアライズは以下のように行いますが
C#ではどのようにすればよいですか？

```
import json

dict = {"test":{"test1":{"test2":"aaa"}}}
dictDump = json.dumps(dict) #シリアライズ
dictLoads = json.loads(dictDump) #デシリアライズ
print(dictLoads["test"]["test1"]["test2"])

#結果：aaa
```

ちょっと調べた感じだと、C#とPythonの文法が違いすぎて理解できませんでした…。

Comment: 文法を理解するのが先ではないでしょうか？ C#では常にはクラスを定義します。そのためJSONをデシリアライズする際、事前に定義したクラスのインスタンスを生成させるのが一般的です。その上で、質問者さんはどうされたいのかによって実現方法が変わってきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#は他のモダンな言語よりもJSONに優しくないイメージがあります。
コメントのアドバイスのように、クラスを理解してJSONの構造をパースすることがC#でJSONを扱う一般的な方法です。
クラスを作成して[DataContractJsonSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer)を使うと.NET Framework純正の環境のみでシリアライズ/デシリアライズできます。

サードパーティーのライブラリを使用可能な環境ならば[Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)を使う方法もあります。

ちなみに「なんで数行のJSON使うだけでクラス作らなきゃいけないんだ！」「私はただDictionaryをJSONにしたいだけなんだ…」というズボラな私は[DynamicJson](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dynamicjson)を使ったりもします。(サードパーティ製のライブラリです)
nugetでライブラリをインストールする方法は割愛しますが、JSONとdynamicなオブジェクトを比較的短いコードで相互置換できます。
以下はサンプルコードです。
(入力補完とコンパイル時のチェックが効かず癖のあるdynamic型と匿名クラスを使いまくるとC#の良さをスポイルする気がしますが…)

参考資料: [C#でJSONを扱う方法まとめ](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/c-sharp-json/#toc-19)

```
using Codeplex.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // DynamicJson ver 1.2.0.0 で動作するコード

            // JsonをdynamicオブジェクトにParse
            dynamic j1 = DynamicJson.Parse(@"{""Greetings"":""Hello World!""}");
            Console.WriteLine(j1.Greetings);            // Hello World!
            dynamic n1 = DynamicJson.Parse(@"{""test"":{""test1"":{""test2"":""aaa""}}}");
            Console.WriteLine(n1.test.test1.test2);     // aaa

            // 匿名クラスをParse
            dynamic j2 = DynamicJson.Parse(DynamicJson.Serialize(new { Greetings = "Hello World!!" }));
            Console.WriteLine(j2.Greetings);            // Hello World!!
            dynamic n2 = DynamicJson.Parse(DynamicJson.Serialize(new { test = new { test1 = new { test2 = "aaa" } } }));
            Console.WriteLine(n2.test.test1.test2);     // aaa

            // 余談: DictionaryをParse
            dynamic j3 = DynamicJson.Parse(DynamicJson.Serialize(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Greetings", "Hello World!!!" } }));
            Console.WriteLine(j3[0].Value);             // Hello World!!!

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DynamicJsonをインストールして使ってみました。直感的で使いやすいです。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

私は厳密に型指定をした `Json` を使う方を推奨します。
プログラムはメンテナンスや、再利用できるかが大事だと思います。

利用するライブラリは 今なら `Newtonsoft.Json`(Json.NET) か `System.Text.Json` ですね。
`System.Text.Json` は Microsoft 製で

```
System.Text.Jsonは、主にパフォーマンス、セキュリティ、標準準拠に重点を置いています。
```

という事です。

コード例は下記の通り： そんなにむつかしくないと思いますが・・。

test.json

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON:API paints my bikeshed!",
      "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
      "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
      "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": {"id": "42", "type": "people"}
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "people",
      "id": "42",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 80,
        "gender": "male"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

コードの例

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;


        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            // Newtonsoft.Json で クラスを定義せず 緩く使う場合
            string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.json");

            JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
            string title = o["data"][0]["attributes"]["title"].Value<string>();
            DateTime? create = o["data"][0]["attributes"]["created"].Value<DateTime?>();

            Console.WriteLine(title);
            Console.WriteLine(create);

            // JSON:API paints my bikeshed!
            // 2015/05/22 14:56:28
        }

        // 使いたいところだけクラス定義します。
        public class TestJson
        {
            public Data[] Data { get; set; }
        }
        public class Data
        {
            public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
        }
        public class Attributes
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test2()
        {
            // Newtonsoft.Json を使う場合
            string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.json");

            var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestJson>(json);
            string title = test.Data.FirstOrDefault()?.Attributes.Title;
            DateTime? create = test.Data.FirstOrDefault()?.Attributes.Created;

            Console.WriteLine(title);
            Console.WriteLine(create);

            // JSON:API paints my bikeshed!
            // 2015/05/22 14:56:28
        }


        [Test]
        public void Test3()
        {
            // System.Text.Json を使う場合
            string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.json");

            JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
            {
                AllowTrailingCommas = true, // 配列の終わりの , を無視
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true, // 大文字小文字の違いを無視
            };
            var test = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestJson>(json, options);
            string title = test.Data.FirstOrDefault()?.Attributes.Title;
            DateTime? create = test.Data.FirstOrDefault()?.Attributes.Created;

            Console.WriteLine(title);
            Console.WriteLine(create);

            // JSON:API paints my bikeshed!
            // 2015/05/22 14:56:28
        }
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。Newtonsoft.JsonでJSONを使用する方法も理解できました。ただ、関数名の前に[Test]という記述をしてあるのは何故なのでしょうか？これがなくても動作しましたが、必要なものなのでしょうか？

Comment: NUnit のテストコードをそのまま張り付けたからです・・。そのテストメソッドだけを個別に実行できるので 試行錯誤するときは  ユニットテストを使って開発すると便利です。